# analogRead always returns 1023 - Arduino Mega 2560

Tags: arduino-mega

I have connected an FSR (Force Sensitive Resistor) to **[image: Arduino Mega 2560]** as per image(edited name for avoiding mismatch). When I measure the voltage b/w two pins of fsr, voltage changing as per pressure applied. But analogRead always returns **1023**. But my another Mega works good with same code and configurations. Can someone guide me to correct it. Thanks in advance.

```cpp
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(19200);
}

void loop() {
  int num1 = analogRead(A15);
  Serial.println(num1);
  delay(1500);
}
```

Comment: 1.  Your code doesn't check the same pin that your schematic shows being connected.   2.  That LED with no current limiting resistor can cause bad things to happen to your board.  That may have something to do with it.

Comment: image is just for reference. In our scenario we connected to A15  and used Mega. Please ignore the LED part and UNO

Comment: So basically the picture is just a total lie that has nothing to do with the question?  Why post it then?  Why not post the actual circuit you used?

Comment: You can't ignore the LED.  It may be the thing causing your problem.

Comment: I dont't know how to make the circuit diagram like the above one.

Comment: Really?  Get a pencil and a piece of paper and draw a schematic.  take a picture and upload.  What's hard about that?  It might not be so pretty but at least it will be right.  And what do you think is more important, that it be pretty or that it be accurate?

Comment: basic debugging includes switching components around ... have you done that? (switch the +5V and the GND connections)

Comment: do some research about voltage dividers

Comment: If mega a works and mega b doesn't with the same circuit then mega b must be broken.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem when I ported my code from an Arduino Due to an Arduino Mega. I was able to solve this problem by adding the following call in the setup function.

```
analogReference(DEFAULT);
```

It seems that in some other Arduinos, the analog reference will be selected automatically, but at least the Arduino Mega needs it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when simulating a similar circuit in proteus software. I was able to solve it by supplying power with an external dc input terminal to the arduino board 5v pin.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your Arduino Mega 2560 is broken.

> If mega a works and mega b doesn't with the same circuit then mega b must be broken. – Majenko

You can confirm this theory by creating a voltage divider circuit (or use a potentiometer as a voltage divider) and get your Arduino Mega to read that in. It is good practice to measure the voltage using a multi-meter as well. This will help you verify that the voltage read in correspond with the voltage measured and will also help so you do not go over-voltage.

If you are constantly getting `1023` then change it to another analog input. If that still does not work, then try the other Arduino Mega.